# Matlab dialog box

Tags: matlab, dialog

please help me:

I want the user to enter a file name containing numbers or/and letters (without a space).

so I have two problems:

1) I tried the next code, but the dialog box is opened and opened and opened.... because I don't know how to edit the 'answer' input without to call the 'inputdlg' again.

2) checking the validity of the file name: I used the 'isempty' and 'strfind' functions, but I know there is an easier option to do this. In my code, I have to check each letter in other case:

```
    while isempty(strfind(answer,'=')) == 0 || isempty(strfind(answer,'*')) == 0 || ...
```

maybe with 'regexp' function, but I don't know how to do this :/

so my code is:

```
prompt={'Enter the File name:'};
name='Input for file name';
numlines=1;
answer=inputdlg(prompt,name,numlines);
while isempty(strfind(answer,'=')) == 0
    answer=inputdlg(prompt,name,numlines);
end
```

Comment: Just a notice - for inputting file names there is `uigetfile` and `uiputfile`. and you know in your test you are looking for the `=` and `*` symbols in the string (which makes it an invalid file name).

Comment: @bdecaf, thank you, but I don't want the user to choose a file from his directory, just to enter a name of the file, and I will create the file (xlsx) with the input name for him (and insert data to the file).

for example: the user inserted: myfile
so I will create a file: myfile.xlsx.
I mean that I just want a name, all the rest I know to do.

Comment: @AlonShmiel: that's exactly what the `uiputfile` function is for..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@bdecaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912411/matlab-dialog-box/10914739#comment14232022_10912411) suggested in the comments, you could use [UIPUTFILE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/uiputfile.html) function to display a "save as" type of dialog:

```
[fName,pName] = uiputfile({'*.xlsx' 'Excel (*.xlsx)'}, 'Save as', 'myfile.xlsx');
if pName==0, error('No file selected'); end
fullName = fullfile(pName,fName);
```

[image: screenshot]

which returns something like:

```
>> fName
fName =
test.xlsx

>> fullName
fullName =
C:\Users\Amro\Documents\example\test.xlsx
```

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `answer` is a cell array. Therefore you should check the contents of the cell array:

```
name='Input for file name';
numlines=1;
answer={''};
% answer=inputdlg(prompt,name,numlines);
while  all( cellfun(@isempty,strfind(answer,'=')) ) 
    answer = inputdlg(prompt,name,numlines);
end
```

In a more global context, I agree with @bdecaf and @Amro, you should use `uigetfile`. Also you can check for validity of file by using `exist(fileName,'file')`